# Creating the XML file on the Another Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, sitemap

I am working on a Web Site, which have 2 domain one for end users(**www.test.com**) and for Admin Panel(**www.admin.test.com**), I am creating the Site map from my Admin section(www.admin.test.com), Now I want when I will create(save) the Site map then My XML file will generate on the Root of the main website(**www.test.com**).

Can any one suggest me how I am achieve this, I am newbie in asp.net.

Comment: "... I have functionality to create the Site map" sounds interesting - you should tell us more about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think both of the domains will be in same physical server, then you can just add path to your physical folder in the test.com site and create xml using it.

If you think that will not be the case, you can simply create a web service on front end that will take care of it.

In most of the cases, first cases is true and you can easily generate xml in www.test.com folder without any problems.

Thanks
Prashant